# Getting error while using Rsync on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, rsync, hpc

I am using rsync, to transfer data to HPC cluster, using Cygwin for windows 7. I type the following command to transfer a folder from my computer to the HPC remote server.

`rsync -rzv /cygdrive/C/Users/LSRATHORE/Desktop/data_wf lsrathore@uahpc.ua.edu
:/home/lsrathore/test`

This produces the following error lines in Cygwin-

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
C:/cygwin64/bin/ssh.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.2.0dev]
```

Comment: In the future, please avoid to double ask on different communities. This is the right place for this question, not StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install or reinstall the package containing cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll
Using `cygcheck -p` to identify it:

```
$ cygcheck -p cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll
Found 6 matches for cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll
krb5-debuginfo-1.15.1-1 - krb5-debuginfo: Debug info for krb5
krb5-debuginfo-1.15.2-1 - krb5-debuginfo: Debug info for krb5
krb5-debuginfo-1.15.2-2 - krb5-debuginfo: Debug info for krb5
libgssapi_krb5_2-1.15.1-1 - libgssapi_krb5_2: Kerberos reference implementation
GSS-API library
libgssapi_krb5_2-1.15.2-1 - libgssapi_krb5_2: Kerberos reference implementation
GSS-API library
libgssapi_krb5_2-1.15.2-2 - libgssapi_krb5_2: Kerberos reference implementation
GSS-API library
```

so it is `libgssapi_krb5_2`

Comment: The root cause of your problem was likely due to incomplete dependecies data on the Cygwin setup.ini for latest OpenSSH package.  https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2020-June/245064.html the problem should be correct now